# Getting value from dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: jquery

would anyone can help me get to get all selected values ​​of dropdownlists. They are created dynamically when I click a button and everybody gets the same id but I can not get all the values ​​and assign them to a field such hidden field, any ideas?

Follows the following code that adds and removes the drop and are now working properly.

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    //some code
});

$("#remove").click(function(){
    //some code
});

<div id="divparent">
    <div id="divchild">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" Width="270"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you try to get the selected value of the drop down list in client side?

Comment: yes, putting in a hidden field

Answer (score 0):

do get the value of the ddl try `var ddlVal = $('#<=%DropDownList3.ClientID%>').val();`

Answer (score 0):

A dropdownlist can only have ONE selected value.

Comment: any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: You could try a ListBox, they allow multiple selections.  (SelectionMode="Multiple")